# Cannot unzip zip file with window 10/11

Tags: javascript, minizip

I encountered a problem cannot unzip certain zip files with Window10/11.

I made a program which one downloads excel files as a zip file by using minizip-asm.min.js library.

Everytime try to unzip this zip file with window10/11, 0x80004005 : Unspecified error.

It can be unzipped by 7zip or such kind of programs, but it is impossible only Windows built-in programs.

How can I fix or handle it?

hers's my js code

```
function gfn_exportExcel(dataJson, fn, pw) {

    var data = dataJson.data;
    var wch = dataJson.wch;

    // step 1.making workbook 
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    // step 2. making excel sheet
    var newWorksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);

    // step 2-2. setting columns
    newWorksheet["!cols"] = gfn_fitToColumnExcel(data, wch);

    // step 3. naming workbook
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, newWorksheet, "data");

    // step 4. making excel file
    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  type: 'binary'});

    // step 5. export excelfile or export files as zip file
    if( pw ){
        var mz = new Minizip();
        mz.append('data.xlsx', gfn_s2ab(wbout), {password : pw});
        saveAs(new Blob([mz.zip()],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), fn + ".zip");
    } else {
        saveAs(new Blob([gfn_s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), fn + ".xlsx");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's likely a limitation in Windows: Windows' ZIP (PKZIP) file handling code has largely been frozen Windows XP, for example, it doesn't support stronger encryption - which you seem to be using. If you need Windows to support it then you'll need to use weaker encryption. I don't know how your library is configured

Comment: BTW, you're using incorrect MIME Content-Types for Office files.

Comment: put it in  a docker container that has the system ultility you're relying on